# Getting padding in fullscreen camera view (FrameLayout)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-camera, android-framelayout

I have this layout:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
 >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Capture" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

`
I am getting black padding in camera view like this, on the right side, notice the vertical black space/strip on right: 
[image]

Don't mind the capture button in middle of screen, I'll position it later. But the question I have is, how to remove the unwanted padding and make FramLayout full screen?

Answer (score 0):

[CameraSourcePreview doesn't fill whole screen height](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/23) that bug fixed by

Comment or remove below lines from CameraSourcePreview.java

```
if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
childHeight = layoutHeight;
childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
}
```

Comment: I'm not using cameraSourcePreview, that you mentioned.